# Make a fullscreen video Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am craeting a video player for the web and I am trying to make the video fullscreen as soon as the user presses a button.So here is my question:

How do i make a website fullscreen in flutter for web?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252120/play-video-in-flutter-web

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am searching something that does the same thing like f11